# Magento page does not load because cookie conflict

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, cookie, persistent

I have exact this problem:

[Maximum execution time exceeded. Clearing cookies only solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87839/maximum-execution-time-exceeded-clearing-cookies-only-solution)

Sometimes and with some users the page does not load, and shows random errors with

> "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of XXXXXXX seconds exceeded in
>   ..."

I'm 90% sure that is something related with the cookie because in private mode loads normally and if I clean my cookies in my browser then loads.

I don't want to disable persistent shopping cart, I don't know if there's a configuration about cookies that I'm missing.

```
Session Cookie Management

Cookie Lifetime: 86400
Cookie Path: 
Cookie Domain:
Use HTTP Only: Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

Comment: check this [once](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88243/live-site-blank-in-frontend-or-keep-on-loading-and-never-load)